# SetUnhandledExceptionFilter not working after rename exe

Tags: winapi, exception

In my test.exe I hook raw windows exception:

```
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(MyTopLevelFilter)
```

It's work fine, but if after call to SetUnhandledExceptionFilter, I rename my test.exe to test_1.exe (while process still running), new exception will not hooked.

How to continue hook exception after rename running process? I can not recall SetUnhandledExceptionFilter because I not know when my process would be renamed.

Comment: Aside: Why do you rename your process exe while it's running? (I didn't think that was possible - learn something new every day).

Comment: This is part of use case my program (this may occured while updating program). But after searching in internet I came to the conclusion that this is feature (or bug) of Windows.